# use TcpClient to send request to server

Tags: c#, http, webserver, tcpclient

I am asking this question primarily because I do not have some ideas clear. I belive I understand how a webserver works but for some reason I am getting different results than expected.

**So basically I want to replicate what I do with a real web browser with code.**

I have a program called Fiddler that acts as a proxy in order to see all the requests and responses from the web server.

**1. So when I open my broser and then goto `http://10.10.10.28/tfs:8080` this is what shows up:**

-------- [image]

.    . . . and this is what fiddler records:

[image]

when I click cancel or attempt to log in other requests will be made and fiddler will record more data. I don't care about that right know I am just interested on simulating this first request.

Anyways so fiddler tels us that the header was:

```
GET http://10.10.10.28/tfs:8080 HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.10.28
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.83 Safari/537.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

and the response was:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.6421
Date: Fri, 24 Aug 2012 14:36:22 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

**2. Finally getting to the fun part the code** Now I will like to send the same header and expect to get the same response. **For some reason I get a different response!**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // I save the header bytes recorded from fiddler on a file to make sure I am sending the exact same request
    byte[] header = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\header");

    // create the client
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient("10.10.10.28", 8080);

    // get the stream so that we can read and write to it
    var stream = client.GetStream();

    // now that we have the stream wait for the server to respond
    WaitForResponse(stream); // waits on a separate thread

    // send the request to the header
    stream.Write(header, 0, header.Length);

    // wait
    Console.Read();
}

public static void WaitForResponse(NetworkStream stream)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
        int responseLength = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        string resp = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, responseLength);
        resp = resp; // place breakpoint
    });
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10); // make sure task starts
}
```

here is the response that I get:
[image]

**Why am I getting a different response?** I believe web servers use a tcp connection to send pages to clients. why is this approach that I am taking not working? Also **why is fiddler not recording anything when I send the request to the web-server from code?** How does Google chrome connect to the web server? I would bet that the chrome browser is establishing also a tcp connection with the web server.

Comment: It seems like you want to specify a port, because your URL contains :8080. If that is the case, you are using the wrong syntax. Use `http://10.10.10.28:8080/tfs` to connect to port 8080, not `http://10.10.10.28/tfs:8080`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you connect to port 8080 and request the URL `http://10.10.10.28/tfs:8080`. So you connect to port 8080 and then request something from port 80. This causes the response of `Bad Request`.

Answer (score 1):

You're connecting to a different server (port 8080 vs port 80).

Also, the request from fiddler looks incorrect. GET doesn't specify the method or hostname. Perhaps this data has been massaged to make it look more friendly?

I would expect the first line of the request to look more like `GET /tfs:8080 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: A request to a proxy usually contains a full URL, as in the example. A request to a normal website *may* contain a full URL.

Comment: yeah that's why I saved the header to a file. you are right they are a little different

Answer (score 0):

You have are trying to read the stream without writing your request first and that's the problem.

Why don't you use HttpWebRequest instead of TcpClient?

Comment: I think using TcpClient instead of HttpWebRequest is part of the homework assignment.

Comment: I placed homework assignment cause I asked this question to learn. I could not figure out why was this not working!

Comment: right, ok. but still, you are reading stream without sending the request (so your request is unknown in this case)